# how can i add or delete 3d object when i click the button

Tags: reactjs, three.js

[image]sorry for if the something i wrote makes you upset. this is the first time to ask question in this site.
thie is the code

```
const canvasRef = useRef(null);
const containerSize = { width: 6.1, height: 2.4, depth: 2.6 };
const palletEx = { width: containerSize.width / 2, height: 0.2, depth: containerSize.depth };
const palletTypeA = { id: 'typeA', width: 1.1, height: 0.15, depth: 1.1 };
const [palletState, setPalletState] = useState(0);
const [pallet, setPallet] = useState(null);
const rendererRef = useRef(null);
const sceneRef = useRef(null);
const [pallets, setPallets] = useState([]);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 1.6, 0.1, 1000);


useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const container = canvas.parentElement;
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneRef.current = scene;

    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas,
        antialias: true,
    });

    rendererRef.current = renderer;

    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    camera.position.x = -1;
    camera.position.y = 3;
    camera.position.z = 25;
    sceneRef.current.camera = camera;

    const containerCube = createCube(containerSize.width, containerSize.height, containerSize.depth);
    scene.add(containerCube);
    containerCube.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    const palletExCube = createCube(palletEx.width, palletEx.height, palletEx.depth);
    scene.add(palletExCube);
    palletExCube.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    canvas.addEventListener("onClick", onClick1);
    const addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
    

    animate();


}, []);



const animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    rendererRef.current.render(sceneRef.current, sceneRef.current.camera);
};
```

and next is the method (it will be executed when i click the button)

```
const onClick1 = () => {
    const newPallet = createCube(palletTypeA.width, palletTypeA.height, palletTypeA.depth);
    sceneRef.current.add(newPallet);
    newPallet.position.set(Math.random()*10, Math.random()*10, Math.random()*10);
    setPallets(prevPallets => [...prevPallets, newPallet]);
};

const onClick2 = () => {

    if (pallets.length > 0) {
        // Remove the last cube from the scene
        const removedPallet = pallets.pop();
        sceneRef.current.remove(removedPallet);
        // Update the cubes state
        setPallets([...pallets]);
    }
};
```

``

I want the pallet to be added to the scene when I press the add button, but the pallet is created and then immediately disappears. I want the pallet to be created only when the add button is clicked and disappear only when the delete button is pressed. Unfortunately, I have to ask for help because I have to do react and three.js, which I don't know at all.